# Newlines not being interpreted when passed to php via the command line

Tags: php, email, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a PHP script that I'm invoking from another shell script that sends an automated email with a message generated from the shell script. Problem is, when I send the message all the newline characters are printed into the message. How do I get them to be interpreted?

sendmail.sh:

```
/path/to/phpscript/sendmail.php "Some Message With Newlines\nHello World.\n"
```

sendmail.php:

```
$message = $argv[1] . "\nNewline";
$smtp->send($to, $from, $message);
```

The odd thing is the \n after the $argv variable is interpreted and actually prints Newline on a new line, but the newlines in the $argv variable don't, I have tried wrapping the variable in double quotes among other things but so far to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about calling your script with *real* newlines :

```
$ php temp.php "Some Message With Newlines
> Hello World.
> "
```

With `temp.php` containing this :

```
var_dump($argv[1]);
```

Gets me the following output :

```
string(40) "Some Message With Newlines
Hello World.
"
```

---

**Edit :** another solution could be to use something like this to call your PHP script :

```
$ echo -e "Some Message With Newlines\nHello World.\n" | php temp.php
```

And, modify your PHP script so it read from [`stdin`,](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) instead of `$argv` :

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));
```